# Popup Video do Vimeo não Abre HTML

Tags: html5, vimeo-api

Estou tentando rodar um vídeo do *vimeo* em um site que estou mexendo.
Ele abre o *popup* do vídeo quando clica no botão, mas aparece a mensagem:

> "Esse vídeo talvez tenha sido movido ou excluído."
>   Mas o vídeo esta lá.

Segue código:

```
<a href="https://vimeo.com/317760843" class="icon popup-vimeo d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
     <span class="icon-play">
</a>
```

Poderiam me ajudar por favor?

Comment: Qual código que abre o *popup*?

Comment: Cara eu testei aqui usando o modal padrão do Bootstrap 4 e funcionou direitinho...

Answer (score 0):

Para rodar um vídeo do vimeo do seu site, você precisa usar a API deles.

```
<div id="vimeo-video"></div>

<script src="https://player.vimeo.com/api/player.js"></script>

<script>
  var options = {
    id: 317760843,
    width: 640,
    loop: true
   };

  var player = new Vimeo.Player('vimeo-video', options);

  player.setVolume(0);

  player.on('play', function() {
    console.log('played the video!');
  });
</script>
```

Esse id do options é o número que está na URL https://vimeo.com/317760843
Quando o vídeo carregar, ele irá aparecer na div com id 'vimeo-video'